# How to write django templates for this

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a method in Python that returns a dict of values as follows:

```
{u'link': u'dns-prefetch'}
{u'link': u'prefetch'}
```

Now my logic is as follows: if link `{u'link': u'dns-prefetch'}` is present then say `"DNS Pre-resolutin is enabled"` and if not say `"DNS Pre-resolutin is not enabled"`. If `{u'link': u'prefetch'}` is present then say `"Page prefetch is enabled"` otherwise say `"Page prefetch is not enabled"`.

How can I write this in Django templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, use `ifequal` for that.

Python view:

```
data_dict = {"DNS": {u'link': u'dns-prefetch'}, "Page": {u'link': u'prefetch'}}
return render_to_response("ABC.html", data_dict)
```

Html Template:

```
<p> DNS:{% ifequal DNS.link 'dns-prefetch'%}DNS Pre-resolutin is enabled{%else%}DNS Pre-resolutin is not enabled{%endifequal%}</p>
<p> Page:{% ifequal Page.link 'prefetch'%} Page prefetch is enabled{%else%}Page prefetch is not enabled{%endifequal%}</p>
```

Comment: My dictionary is not like the data_dict . It is just {u'link': u'dns-prefetch'}
{u'link': u'prefetch'}

Comment: ok, I am not getting.
How you pass these python dictionary to your templates and how you call url? means by render_to_response or HttpResponse (Javascript) ??

Comment: By render_to_response

Comment: We need to pass these dictionaries in the key and value formats to template by the render_to_response method. 
like {"values":[{u'link': u'dns-prefetch'},{u'link': u'prefetch'}]}

Checking more solution. Can you shear your python code means how you are passing these values to render_to_response function.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for d in values %}
    <div>
    {% ifequal d.link 'dns-prefetch' %}
        DNS Pre-resolutin is enabled
    {% else %}
        DNS Pre-resolutin is not enabled
    {% endifequal %}
    </div>
    <div>
    {% ifequal d.link 'prefetch' %}
        Page prefetch is enabled
    {% else %}
        Page prefetch is not enabled
    {% endifequal %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is your input to HTML file i.e. render dictionary? data_dict in following statement?
return render_to_response("ABC.html", data_dict)

Comment: How do you pass "dict of values" to template?  Is this a list of dicts of just single dict?  Show us the code, please.